# Multiple ip ban, read from file IP's -> ban in iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

How I can read out IP addresses from file and then ban in iptables.

88.123.xxx
123.456.xxx
65.234.xxx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple, direct, one line solution:

```
for IP in $(cat ip_list); do iptables -A INPUT -s $IP/32 -d 0/0 -j DROP; done
```

This will block any communication from the ip addresses on any protocol or port.

But maybe you should think about doing a proper firewall script using `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` or even [Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/).

*EDIT:* The same line, verbose:

```
for IP in $(cat ip_list); do echo "Banning $IP"; iptables -A INPUT -s $IP/32 -d 0/0 -j DROP; done
```

Comment: It's worth learning to do this from memory. It's very useful to be able to create a loop whenever you want in bash.

Comment: Very nice! Maybe it is possible to make verbose this line? I see nothing while it is working.

Comment: And one last little question: it is possible to duplicate a line in iptables (for example: I add two same IP address)? If yes how I can remove duplicates from iptables?

Comment: @user Yes it is possible, doesn't mean much unless you forget that they're duplicated :) And to remove you use `iptables -D INPUT <n>` where <n> is the rule number (start counting 1 from the first rule). There's no way to automatically remove a duplicate unless you write a script to check for duplicates.

Comment: @user666 added a *verbose* line.

Comment: @coredump: $(cat ip_list | sort | uniq ) will remove dupes

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I am going to learn more about iptables. Bash is a beautiful language, I love it very much!

Comment: @iain on the original file sure, I thought he was asking from the `iptables -L` list.

Comment: hm, it would be wise to do check what is output of iptables-save before applying this because with -A INPUT rules are appended at the end of input chain which leaves the possibility of ACCEPT rule allowing the traffic earlier on in the chain, so rather -I INPUT than -A INPUT in my opinion...

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
while read ipaddr
do
    /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s $ipaddr -j DROP
done </path/to/iplist-to-drop | sort | uniq
~
```

Or using a separate chain

```
#!/bin/bash

/sbin/iptables -N Dropped-From-File
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j Dropped-From-File
while read ipaddr
do

    /sbin/iptables -I Dropped-From-File -s $ipaddr -j DROP
done </path/to/iplist-to-drop | sort | uniq


/sbin/iptables -A Dropped-From-File -j RETURN
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also use module ipset ( http://ipset.netfilter.org/ ). When list of ip addresses gets long, matching them one by one with individual iptables rules will lead to degraded performance. Ipset should perform much better. Also, with ipset you can reload addresses at any time without touching your rules.

Even if you dont want to bother with ipset, it is better to drop banned addresses in iptables "raw" table. This way, connection tracking framework will not see them and won't create state records you'll never need. This should also improve performance in case the firewall has to handle lots of traffic.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `ipset` and table `raw`, as vadimk said. Here is how you do it

```
apt-get install ipset
ipset -N badips iphash
while read ip; do ipset -A badips "$ip"; done < badips.txt
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -m set --match-set badips src,dst -j DROP
```

To make this rules persistent on reboot on Debian 7 i had to use [modified iptables-persistent](https://github.com/jordanrinke/ipsets-persistent)

```
/etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save
```